Simplified Explanation of Coleman-Weinberg Potential in QFT
I have been reading a research paper where the interaction potential between two scalar fields is given by $$=g\,  \phi H^\dagger H .$$ The Coleman-Weinberg correction to the potential is: $$ \frac{n}{64\pi^2} (-1)^{2s}{{m}^4}
\left( \ln\left( \frac{{{m}^2} 
}{\mu^2} \right) - c \right),$$ where $m$ is function of $\phi$ and $n$ and $s$ depend on the degrees of freedom of $H$.
I have a basic understanding of QFT, but I would like to understand the physics behind this correction. Could someone explain this in simple terms?

Which research paper? Which page?
